# Cannot send a message between client and server using socket.io in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and trying to implement the socket.io in my app. I guess i am doing everything right but still it's not working.

Here are my code snippets :

*App.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
// window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: 'Hello World!'
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.socket = io('http://192.168.1.24:19001'/*, {transports: ['websocket']}*/);
        this.socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        this.socket.on('update', () => {
            console.log('yay');
            this.setState({name: 'Done did it!'})
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
});
```

I have created a folder 'server' which has the following codes:

*server/app.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen('19001', '192.168.1.24');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.on('update', () => {
        console.log('update');
        socket.emit('update')
    });
});
```

I made a html page to interact to the app.

*server/index.html*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen('19001', '192.168.1.24');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.on('update', () => {
        console.log('update');
        socket.emit('update')
    });
});
```

I tried using localhost too instead of IP address. That didn't work either.

**Please Help!**

Comment: can you put the right code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why did you use `'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'`? I think the client of socket.io it’s just `'socket.io-client'`.
2. It is not recommend to call this.setState in your constructor even through it is inside a callback function. You could update the state when the screen isn’t rendered yet and it’ll throw an error. Try to move your listeners inside componentDidMount.
3. Are you sure the connection is done?! If yes then try to move your listener to 'update' event inside your 'connect' event’s callback.
4. Your server is listening on 19001 port. I think it’s also the default port of react native packager. Is your server starting? Have you try another port like 80 other 8080 if you don’t have root access.

Comment: @mcssymI do everything you say but it doesn't work, but the log is worked when i clicked the button

Comment: @Gha I can‘t help you of i don‘t see your code. Maybe you habe amother thing to do!

Comment: @Gha So I don’t see what could be the problem. I’ve already listed all solutions I know for this case.

Comment: can you check that here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615964/send-a-message-between-client-and-server-is-not-fine-i-using-socket-io-in-react