# send a message between client and server is not fine i using socket.io in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use Socket.io with react native App but I have some issue between client side and server side, I think is the code right but it doesn't update the state when clicked the button, the connection is done and I show the log worked I don't show any error in them!

that is my code :

server/app.js

```
var app = require("express")();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.on("update", () => {
    console.log("update con");
    socket.emit("update");
  });
});
```

server/index.html

```
<h1>Welcome Socket.io !!</h1>
<button>Update</button>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
  var socket = io();
  var btn = document.querySelector("button");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    console.log("update func");
    socket.emit("update");
  };
</script>
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
window.navigator.userAgent = "react-native";
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "HelloWorld"
    };
    this.socket = io("localhost:8080", { jsonp: false });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.on("update", () => {

      this.setState({ name: "updated name !" });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. You have a server and two clients. If the Android project connects, you should see two ids in the server log. 2. you're sending "update" back to your JS client, not your react-native client

Comment: @ChrisG I have two ids in the server log correctly, can you explain what you mean in Num 2 with my code

Comment: 1. open the browser on the Genymotion device and try to visit the server. For me it's `http://192.168.220.10:8080`. Once you manage to, put that exact URL in the react native code's `io()` 2. in your server code, change `socket.emit("update");` to `io.emit("update");` so the message is sent to all clients

Comment: @ChrisG i do that but the issue is still :(

Comment: it works for me. If you want help, you need to be a bit more specific. Did you set the Genymotion device to bridge mode? Can you see your express server's index.html on the Genymotion browser?

Comment: what do you mean of bridge mode? yes i see the server in the Genymotion browser

Comment: In the Genymotion settings for my device, I can set the network to bridge mode at the bottom. If I do that, the device is connected to my LAN like any other device. Shouldn't matter as long as you can see the express server. So to recap: you can see the server, and you're getting the ID logged. Double-check it's the Android ID by displaying it in your app. Next, make sure that the server sends to all clients. Add a basic reaction to your HTML client, open it in two browsers, then click update and check if it reaches the other client. Just narrow down the issue.

Comment: @ChrisG that is work bro I think the issue she was with bridge mode! thank you a lot, can you suggest any videos or posts Blog for Socket in react native?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from the address of your socket server. In `App.js` you wrote localhost but if it’s in mobile so emulator or device, then your address can’t be `localhost`. It could 10.0.2.2 for emulator Android or your pc address on the WiFi shared by your pc and your device.

Comment: in the first I use Genymotion, and I change the address to http://192.168.1.108 and still the port 8080, but doesn't work anymore

Comment: Okay I ever used genymotion for that! Have you try to put http:// before localhost or replace localhost by 128.0.0.1???

Comment: @Gha try this `this.socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:8080', { transport: ['websocket', 'pooling'] })`

Comment: And 'update' is not automatically Sent when the user connect. So you won’t receive this event unless you emit it first. Like you do on your client browser

Comment: So what i change now?

Comment: Or rather than emitting in your server you can broadcast so everyone connected will receive the event. And make search everyone is connected before broadcasting.

Comment: @mcssym did you mind having a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121600/app-stops-working-when-i-keep-sending-multiple-messages-with-socket-io/74125965#74125965